# How can I look up a @Singleton by name in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a class structure that looks like this:

```
abstract class A {
  abstract int getNumber()
}

@Singleton
class AA extends A {
  @Override
  int getNumber() { return 1 }
}

@Singleton
class AB extends A {
  @Override
  int getNumber() { return 2 }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
A myInstance = GroovyAwesomeness.getSingletonInstanceByName("AA")
```

but no such awesomeness exists (that I know of). Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: In your code sample you've defined an abstract base class A but neither of the other two classes extend it. Your code should fail to compile because neither of the methods marked `@Override` are overriding.

Comment: Should be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The inheritance wasn't relevant to the question, so I removed it

Comment: I put it back because it is relevant. I need to be able to do "dependency injection" (not really, but kinda) with this in my code, so if having it in this context changes the solution someone might provide I want it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to just use the `ClassLoader`:

```
Class<A> myClass = this.class.classLoader.loadClass "AB"
assert 2 == myClass.instance.number
```

IDEs will complain, however, because of the lack of a `getInstance` method on `Class`.